# Api Refresh in Python

Tags: python, api, error-handling, request

im heading an error in my code now:
method generates a runtime error: '%d format: a number is required, not str'.
I cant understand why its throwing this error now and which variable is meant by that

```
import requests

def vorschlagen(typ,aufwand):
    if typ not in ["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"]:
        raise ValueError("falsche Eingabe")

    url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&?accessiblity={aufwand}"

    while True:
        
        data=requests.get(url).json()
        link=(data["link"])
        name=(data["activity"])
        typ=(data["type"])

        aufwand=(data["accessibility"])
        print("Aktivität :",name)
        print("Art der Aktivität (TYP) :",typ)
        print("Link :",link)
        print("len data[link]:", len(link))
        print("Aufwand :",aufwand)
        
        if len(data["link"]) > 0:
            return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)
vorschlagen("social",1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error ... I ran the script several times and it runs without any problems ... can you paste the entire error stack trace?

Comment: I am running it on a VPL and the evaluation says that.

Comment: check that the values returned by the function are those required?

Comment: its kinda weird because in vsc there are no errors.

Comment: The `&?` in the URL seems to be incorrect.

Comment: You mean the "?" i guess? Or what is the correct url for these queries?

Comment: `url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&accessiblity={aufwand}"` 

Also, check that `return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)` is the expected value for the exercise

Answer (score 0):

In the `url` the parameter `accessiblity` must be `accessibility`:

```
import requests

def vorschlagen(typ,aufwand):
    if typ not in ["education", "recreational", "social", "diy", "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork"]:
        raise ValueError("invalid argument typ")

    url=f"http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type={typ}&accessibility={aufwand}"

    while True:
        
        data=requests.get(url).json()
    
        link=(data["link"])
        name=(data["activity"])
        typ=(data["type"])
        aufwand=(data["accessibility"])
        
        print("Aktivität :",name)
        print("Art der Aktivität (TYP) :",typ)
        print("Link :",link)
        print("len data[link]:", len(link))
        print("Aufwand :",aufwand)
        
        if len(data["link"]) > 0:
            return (name),(typ),(link),(aufwand)
```

Also, you should handle service responses that contain no activity.

For example, checking the condition `if 'error' in data`